# Not receiving push notification on Expo iOS client

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am working on an app using push notifications.
The problem is I am not receiving push notifications on iOS devices even with the Push Notification Tool.

On Android, everything works well. I 've uninstalled/reinstalled and logged out from the expo iOS client but the problem still persists. The only notable change I made in my app was updating to SDK v33.

Any idea on what could be the problem?

Comment: did you tried push in debugging mode?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by debugging mode. I am already on dev mode on Expo.

Comment: Was there no problem with the old version?

Comment: The doc is not crystal clear about how to test Push Notifications on iOS. Although, with Expo 33, we now have a way to build a custom Expo Client, with (reading the doc) working Push Notifications - cf https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/guides/adhoc-builds/.

I haven't tried it, and we have the same problem, be sure to update this issue when you've found a solution!

Comment: @hongdevelop The former version I was using was SDK 31 (one of my colleagues reported not receiving push notification sometimes). When SDK 33 came out I made the upgrade. When I noticed that I also could not receive push notifs, I decided to revert back To SDK 31 but doing that didn't solve the issue. I finally decided to stick with SDK 33

Comment: I think they are trying to make it work but some details are missing, there is an incoming PR to the docs stating that Push Notifications are disabled : https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/4674/files#diff-d232fa6700c44c44fc4ea311008626efR143.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Common reasons why this could be happening

1. IOS requires notification permission to be granted for each app.
2. IOS does not show notification when app is in foreground.

You can check it by attaching a notification listener.

Comment: Genius! I didn't know that IOS doesn't show notification with app actived.

Comment: This was making me crazy.  Thanks for clarifying that notifications don't show when the app is in focus.

Comment: For the record, this behaviour can be changed by editing the app.json file with "iosDisplayInForeground": true.